# Using Unity and Photon PUN, Is there a way to synchronize alterations to a tilemap changed at runtime with SetTile()?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

I've been having this issue for a while now and was wondering how to fix it. Basically I have a tree tile and when I left click while my mouse hovers over the tree, it's tile is set to null and an item is spawned. Now, the item spawning works fine but the tree tile being st to null doesn't synchronize over to other clients. Any fixes?

```
void BreakDecor()
{
    GameObject spawnedItem = PhotonNetwork.Instantiate("Item", new Vector3(selectedTile.x + 0.5f, selectedTile.y + 0.5f), Quaternion.identity);
    spawnedItem.GetComponent<ItemObjectHolder>().item = ItemDirectory.instance.itemDirectory[decor.GetTile<TileBase>(selectedTile).name];
    decor.SetTile(selectedTile, null);
}
void Update()
{
    Vector3 point = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        if (point.x - player.transform.position.x < distanceFromPlayer && player.transform.position.x - point.x < distanceFromPlayer && point.y - player.transform.position.y < distanceFromPlayer && player.transform.position.y - point.y < distanceFromPlayer)
        {
            selectedTile = decor.WorldToCell(point);
            if (decor.GetTile(selectedTile) != null)
            {
                BreakDecor();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `[PunRPC]` to tell everyone else to set it to null. Photon won't know to synchronize something unless you tell it to.
Read [here](https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/pun/current/gameplay/rpcsandraiseevent) for more.

```
void BreakDecor()
{
    GameObject spawnedItem = PhotonNetwork.Instantiate("Item", new Vector3(selectedTile.x + 0.5f, selectedTile.y + 0.5f), Quaternion.identity);
    spawnedItem.GetComponent<ItemObjectHolder>().item = ItemDirectory.instance.itemDirectory[decor.GetTile<TileBase>(selectedTile).name];
    PhotonView.RPC("RPC_DecorBrocken", RpcTarget.All, selectedTile.ID);
}

[PunRPC]
private void RPC_DecorBrocken(string _tileID)
{
    //Set selectedTile from the _tileID
    selectedTile = decor.getTileFromID(_tileID);
    decor.SetTile(selectedTile, null);
}
```

Comment: Well yes and no .. the are multiple ways of synchronizing stuff in PUN .. using RPC is one of them .. there is also e.g. `OnPhotonSerializeView` which might be better for frequent updates!

Comment: @derHugo Yes you are right, I see how I worded my answer badly.

Comment: should my tilemap also have a photonview component using this? and should i send the rpc with tielmap.photonview.RPC or player.PhotonVieww.RPC?

Comment: @NivMizzer either will work you just need to have a system to make sure the client and host are accessing the same objects. It will probably make more sense if the tilemap handles that kind of information.